# Why adding lang=less to the style of a Vue component changes existing behaviour?

Tags: css, vue.js, less, vue-component

I have a Vue component and would like to scope its CSS. Before discovering the right way (via the [`scoped` attribute](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html)), I had a plan to use `less` in order to encapsulate my CSS entries.

I had an initial  section which was working as expected:

```
<style>
    #weather {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
        text-align: center;
        grid-column-gap: 5px;
    }

    .hour {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        justify-self: start;
        padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
        color: white !important;
    }
    .date {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .today {
        grid-column: 1 / 5;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .tomorrow {
        grid-column: 5 / 9;
    }
</style>
```

After just changing the first line to `<style lang=less>`, I expected **not to have any changes yet**. I thought that less was backward-compatible with CSS and if I do not use anything specific to `less`, I would end with the same CSS.

This was not the case, my page got disturbed. DevTools shows that

[image]

This would suggest that the `display` is not `grid` anymore and therefore `grid-column` does not make sense.

**What have changed by adding `lang=less` to `<style>`?** Specifically: why is the CSS treated differently while the CSS code has not changed yet?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `e` function for `grid-column` value to prevent less to compile `1 / 5` to `0.2`.

```
 .today {
        grid-column: e("1 / 5");
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .tomorrow {
        grid-column: e("5 / 9");
    }
```

Or you can simply do it like this:

```
.today {
    grid-column: ~"1 / 5";
    font-weight: bold;
}
.tomorrow {
    grid-column: ~"5 / 9";
}
```

For more information, you can check **[Escaping](http://lesscss.org/#escaping)** topic in less.

Comment: In this case, though, it seems like the `grid-column: 0.2;` was correctly interpreted; however, as @WoJ pointed out in his screen shot, it was not properly applied, so the suggestion that "the `display` is not `grid` anymore" makes sense. It's likely something to do with the `#weather` selector.